Guacamole with HTTP authentication
I am having hard time understanding guacamole manual on how to configure http header on guacamole.
I have installed guacamole-auth-header-1.5.5.jar and mounted it. When i start my docker compose in logs i see that auth-header didn't start. And i am not sure if i mounted it wrong or what could the problem be.
I would appreciate any help on how to configure HTTP header with guacamole.
I tried mounting auth-header to guacamole i wanted to get to guacamole using HTTP header authentication.
